# (Groovy | 12.04 | armv7l) Install from Source Desktop

Tags: robotic-arm, ubuntu, ubuntu-precise, source, ros-groovy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

```
$ wstool init -j8 src h t t p://packages.ros.org/web/rosinstall/generate/raw/groovy/desktop
```

I am having issues with some packages (flann, opencv2, cv_bridge, image_geometry, collada_parser, camera_info_manager, rqt_image_view, rosbag, diagnostic_analysis, interactive_markers, pcl, urdf, ... will continue adding while I continue...)

I ended up erasing those directories `rm -rf src/flann`,  `rm -rf src/opencv2`,... and running

```
./src/catkin/bin/catkin_make_isolated --install --install-space /opt/ros/groovy
```

Is there a way to bypass the errors so that it does not make from the beginning and just continue were it left? Also, is there another way to correctly install these?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/56015/(groovy-%7C-12.04-%7C-armv7l)-install-from-source-desktop/) by [amrivera](https://answers.ros.org/users/3700/amrivera/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2013-02-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you run catkin_make_isolated again, it will kind of continue where it left, since it will not do anything for completed packages.

---

Originally posted by [KruseT](https://answers.ros.org/users/888/kruset/) with karma: 7848 on 2013-02-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you are using an ARM, I would assume you do not have 8 core, so I would suggest running

```
wstool init -j1 src http://packages.ros.org/web/rosinstall/generate/raw/groovy/desktop
```

It might also take a long while until all files are downloaded, so I would assume you did not give the packages enough time to download.
You will run into more problems when trying to compile, so I would suggest looking into [this tutorial](http://www.ros.org/wiki/groovy/Installation/Linaro/Source)

---

Originally posted by [kalectro](https://answers.ros.org/users/3904/kalectro/) with karma: 1554 on 2013-02-22

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [KruseT](https://answers.ros.org/users/888/kruset/) on 2013-02-22**:
Most of the time is spent on IO, so even with one CPU -j8 can be good, I believe.

**Comment by [kalectro](https://answers.ros.org/users/3904/kalectro/) on 2013-02-22**:
When I compile on ARM, it also takes a while to go through all packages but that will not be sped up by using multiple cores. Multiple cores will only be used within single packages. If you look at the tutorial I linked, it also explains how to set up a chroot to make it compile faster

**Comment by [amrivera](https://answers.ros.org/users/3700/amrivera/) on 2013-02-25**:
I am in the process of following your tutorial, but am having problems when creating the image. I am posting the output below.